# Related questions without titles

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta, related-questions

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300894/295232) has some interesting links under Related questions: the links don't have titles.

[image]

A little investigation shows that's not surprising; they link to *answers* instead of questions, and those don't have titles:

- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269627/?rq=1
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291168/?rq=1

Comment: easy repro: the same thing now happens in the Related section of **this** question